# What order do I call glActiveTexture and glBindTexture

Tags: opengl

I am wondering about when I have a texture named tex which I create with `glBindTexture(...)` and `glTexImage2D(...)`.

If I want to bind it to a specific texture unit, when do I call `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All texture state functions operate on the current texture unit, so first you call `glActiveTexture`, then `glBindTexture` and friends.